# How to access element of a dynamically added array in angular 4?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript, key-value

```
  service=[];

     todoDetails()
     {
      this.service.push({id:++this.lastId,name:this.st,complete:this.complete});
     }
```

//adding elements at runtime

How to access the elements which are added at runtime to serice[]?

Comment: @lancovici OP means the service array

Answer (score 1):

To access an array, just use bracket and index

```
this.service[<index>]

console.log(this.service[0].id);
console.log(this.service[0].name);
```